Is this the right side to crimp the spade connector?

I used to crimp non insulated spade connectors by pressing
the side of the seam with the crimping tool tooth.
Then,i saw in youtube that the proper way(?)is to press the
other side of the spade,as you may see in the photo,while the seam is located into the smooth area.
So,what should the crimping tool tooth need to press:
the seam side or the opposite side?
UPDATE:


I've been crimping wires for decades and always wondered about this.

Me too,so how do you make the crimp,press the tooth on the split side or the other side?

the connector in the picture is too large for the wire ... it should be a tighter fit

the crimper is oriented correctly ... if used in the opposite orientation, then the connector seam would get pushed apart ... there are crimpers that fold both sides of the seam

@jsotola,do you mean that the crimping tool that used to crimp the connector,like the one in my update photo,is the proper way to crimp the one with the seam?

the connector in the second photo uses a different crimper

I used to get the split side to "double over" so the tool or crimp needs turning over.
But there will be many opinions, this is just mine, in my defence I was an auto electrician and used many many of these cripms red, blue, yellow and also soldered many...

In regards to the many opinions,i don't think that it is related to opinions how to make a proper crimp,i think that there is one proper method(engineer design)to use this crimping tool with this type of connectors(seam/split),but unfortunately i haven't find any manual that explain the proper way yet.

Look at all the machine made ones - the split side is forced down much like the top of a drawn heart.

Okay,i finally find the manual around the net.It appear that the proper way to crimp those non-insulating connector is actually the way  that you ,Solar Mike,mentioned and also as i always used to do.The indentor(tooth)of the crimping tool should press the seam/split side. Youtube video is wrong!
